# Error XMLHttpRequest no esta definido

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

El problema surge a la hora de generar una llamada XMLHttpRequest, definiéndola de la siguiente manera

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Al intentar compilar el archivo JavaScript desde la consola de localhost, genera el siguiente error

**

> ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

**

He instalado [node-XMLHttpRequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) y redefinido de la siguiente manera

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var request= new XMLHttpRequest();

//Estado de la peticion
request.addEventListener('readystatechange', (e) => {
    if (e.target.readyState === 4) {
        const datos = JSON.parse(e.target.responseText);
        console.log(datos);
    }
})

//Apertura de url
request.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

//Envio de la peticion
request.send();
```

Desde url esto funciona pero no desde consola, es posible ejecutar estas consultas desde consola?

Comment: _Node_ tiene una extensión para ejecutar [peticiones HTTP](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/) y, seguramente, vas a poder lograr lo que buscas sin mayor problema.